# How to load json file in Karma test in angularjs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

For my angularjs app to work I need to get and parse a config file (a json file) when the application starts. This is done by `$http.get(url)`

The URL used when running the app is: `localhost:9091/config/config.json`

What should the URL be when running my Karma tests, `config/config.json` ?

My test hangs at `$http.get(url)` when running the test. No success and no error.
Should I load the config file some other way? Do I need to config my Karma task in my Gruntfile to include this file?

**Update**: I've now included the config.json file in my files list in the Karma task and I can access the file from my browser during the test run on:
`http://localhost:9876/base/config/config.json`. The `get` request from the test is however still not working (it just hangs).

**Update 2**: When running the tests and looking in the Network tab in Chrome I can see that no request is made to `http://localhost:9876/base/config/config.json`. Could it be angular-mock that is stopping the request?

Karma task in my Gruntfile:

```
karma: {
  options: {
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [  //this files data is also updated in the watch handler, if updated change there too
      '<%= dom_munger.data.appjs %>',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      createFolderGlobs('*-spec.js'),
      {pattern: 'config/config.json', watched: true, included: false, served: true},
    ],
    logLevel:'ERROR',
    reporters:['mocha'],
    autoWatch: false, //watching is handled by grunt-contrib-watch
    singleRun: true
  },
  all_tests: {
    browsers: ['PhantomJS','Chrome','Firefox']
  },
  during_watch: {
    browsers: ['PhantomJS']
  },
},
```

Comment: Is the issue intercepting the `$http.get()` call, or is the issue loading the data from `config.json`?

Comment: The issue is that config.json never gets loaded in the test. The `get` request just hangs.